# SDL_Log outputting ??" when trying to output a string

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I've been trying to send a log in the console to make sure the player was created, but here is the results:

[image: Console Outputs]

Here is the code along the problematic part:

```
SDL_Log("%s has %i hp out of %i", player1.name, player1.health, player1.maxhealth);
```

systemValues.h:

```
// Core Libraries and Headers
// - Global includes
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

// Defines
#define GRAPHICS "../resources/"

struct Player
{
  std::string sprite;
  std::string name;
  int level;
  int size;
  int health;
  int maxhealth;
  int magicpower; // Magic Points
  int damages;
  int armor;
  int magic;
};

struct Enemy
{
  std::string sprite;
  std::string name;
  int level;
  int size;
  int health;
  int maxhealth;
  int magicpower; // Magic Points
  int damages;
  int armor;
  int magic;
};

Player createPlayer(std::string name);
Enemy createEnemy(std::string name, int level);

int damagePlayer(Player target, int damages);
int damageEnemy(Enemy target, int damages);

void close();
```

main.cpp:

```
// Local includes
// - Custom Headers
#include "systemValues.h"

// Screen constants and dimensions. (TODO: MOVE TO A PROPER HEADER FILE.)
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

// The window that is rendered to
SDL_Window* window = NULL;

// Quit being false means the application is running and did not request to quit
bool quit = false;

// Event handler
SDL_Event e;

// The surface contained by the window
SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;

// Main function
int main(int argc, char* args[])
{

  // Initializing SDL
  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)<0)
  {
    SDL_Log("SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
  }
  else
  {
    // Creating the window
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
      SDL_Log("The window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }
    else
    {

      Player player1 = createPlayer("Avarthar");
      Enemy enemy1 = createEnemy("Blob", 1);

      // Get the window surface
      screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

      // While the application is running
      while (!quit){
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
        {
          // User requests quit
          if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
          {
            quit = true;
          }
          // Checks for a key being pressed down
          else if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
          {
            switch(e.key.keysym.sym)
            {
              // Checks if the key is F
              case SDLK_f:
                player1.health = damagePlayer(player1, 5);
                SDL_Log("%s has %i hp out of %i", player1.name, player1.health, player1.maxhealth); // TODO - Remove the test line
                break;
              case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                quit = true;
                break;
            }
          }
        }

        // Test if player is created
        if (player1.name == "Avarthar")
        {
          SDL_FillRect(screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(screenSurface->format, (player1.health*-1+100*2), player1.health*2, 0));
        }
        else
        {
          SDL_FillRect(screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(screenSurface->format, 255, 255, 255));
        }
        // Update the surface
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
      }
    }
  }

  close();

  // Return 0 to terminate the program
  return 0;
}

// Creates a player with the given varables 
Player createPlayer(std::string name)
{
  Player player;
  player.sprite = "";
  player.name = name;
  player.level = 1;
  player.size = 32;
  player.health = 100;
  player.maxhealth = 100;
  player.magicpower = 100;
  player.damages = 1;
  player.armor = 0;
  player.magic = 1;

  return player;
}

Enemy createEnemy(std::string name, int level)
{
  Enemy enemy;
  enemy.sprite = "";
  enemy.name = name;
  enemy.level = level;
  enemy.size = 32;
  enemy.health = 100;
  enemy.maxhealth = 100;
  enemy.magicpower = 100; // Magic Points
  enemy.damages = 1;
  enemy.armor = 0;
  enemy.magic = 1;

  return enemy;
}

// Deals damage to the target of type Player
int damagePlayer(Player target, int damages)
{
  target.health -= damages;

  // Checks whether the target is in the health range or not
  if (target.health < 0)
    target.health = 0;
  if (target.health > target.maxhealth)
    target.health = target.maxhealth;

  return target.health;
}

// Deals damage to the target of type Enemy
int damageEnemy(Enemy target, int damages)
{
  target.health -= damages;

  // Checks whether the target is in the health range or not
  if (target.health < 0)
    target.health = 0;
  if (target.health > target.maxhealth)
    target.health = target.maxhealth;

  return target.health;
}

void close()
{
  // Wait 0.1 seconds
  SDL_Delay(100);

  // Clear the window from the memory
  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

  // Quit the SDL subsystems
  SDL_Quit();
}
```

What I tried so far:

- I tried with `&player1.name` and it didn't change anything.
- I also tried with only `SDL_Log("%s", player1.name);` and it instead wrote a single `?` in the outputs.

The color changing according to the `player1.health` is working without any problem, but as soon as I try getting and sending the name in the `SDL_Log` it sends the outputs shown in the screenshot above.

Comment: `SDL_Log` cannot do `std::string`. Use `player1.name.c_str()`. This should have triggered a warning, check your compiler flags.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked like a charm ^^

Comment: How can I get to print the outputs in a mingwx64 console? (Using makefile to compile, windows 7)

Comment: That's another question altogether -- post it as one, and take care of including relevant code and info directly into the question :)

Answer (score 2):

> `SDL_Log` cannot do `std::string`. Use `player1.name.c_str()`. This should have triggered a warning, check your compiler flags. – Quentin

Thanks for the quick answer and also thanks for noticing another problem that I had with my compiler ^^